# How to add a click handler to MenuItems created by a data binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, click, menuitem

and now the details...

First if all this is my first encounter with WPF so please forgive I am missing something obvious etc.

What I have is a Menu with Menu Items bound to a DataView each menu item is a Row in DataView MenuItem Text is set to a Field in Row... menu is populated well and I can see all rows listed there! but when clicked nothing happens.

My Problem is how I can assign a click event to Menu Item, below is the XAML of ItemPresenter of parent menuitem

```
<MenuItem Name="mnuRowsDropDown" Header="All Rows ▼" 
                          Height="23" 
                          Loaded="mnuNotesDropDown_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="MenuItem.Click" Value="" />-->
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

As you can see here I commented the Click Code because designed said it is an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special setter for that called [`EventSetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx), use that instead. *(When creating `MenuItems` dynamically it may be of interest to use [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) instead as those can easily be included in the object you use for the binding along with the Header)*

Comment: Thanks! I Knew it must be something simple, and I would really like to switch to commands as you suggested.